# How to copy previous settings after the first try?

Tags: customization

So I just downloaded 2.71 (YAY!) and tried the super-handy "copy previous settings" option on the splashscreen...

...but Blender froze (prolly cuz I had another instance open at the time). No worries, I'll kill it and try again...

...except it's not on the splashscreen anymore. Well (says I) it's gotta be somewhere: <kbd>space</kbd> "copy prev..." yup! There it is!

...But it throws the error: "[such-and-such-directory]/Blender/2.71 exists!"

...Well, I guess I can delete the existing directory (and whatever record it had) and just re-extract...

...But it still remembers!

**So the question is, how do I get Blender to copy the previous settings, if it thinks it already has?**

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I thought things had changed since then. (Would "it's the same as 2.6 versions" be an acceptable answer?)

Comment: The reason it remembers is because it created a directory in the [user path](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout) (`~/.config/blender`, or `%APPDATA%` if you are on windows). AFAIK This stuff hasn't changed significantly in a long time (no real reason for it to :). If things do change, then we can update the old post.